# Keyboard events before and after a character was typed

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I am searching for a possibility to compare the text before and after a character was typed. Therefore i need the text directly before and after the character is inserted by the browser.

I already tried the keydown/keyup events but the problem is that if you are typing to fast multiple down events are triggered before the up event for the first key is fired. Furthermore i tried the keypress (before/after) event but after keypress the character is not yet inserted.

Is it possible to get a event directly before and after the character is inserted for every single character (even when typing fast)?

Comment: cant you base your comparism between the value of the input on the first keydown and the value of the input in the next keydown since the keyup gets cancelled when you type too fast?

Comment: The problem is that if multiple characters are inserted between checks i don't know how to get the exactly inputed text ("Hello" vs. "Hellllo" which "l"s were inserted?). "since the keyup gets cancelled" i cannot confirm this as standard behaviour, or do you mean to implement this by myself?

Comment: you have to ask yourself if you are implementing the right event handler or a combination of more than one event handler to achieve what u want.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what the question in this post is about ;) I don't know what other events (or combinations) i could use as all events i tried didn't work for me.